# Spring rest docs request url shows value for path parameter instead of the parameter name

Tags: spring-restdocs, spring-auto-restdocs

I use spring rest docs to document my api.

Now I want to document my document my path in the form of

```
.../accounts/{userId}
```

but I get

```
.../accounts/123
```

The test part look as follows:

```
 mockMvc.perform(RestDocumentationRequestBuilders.get("/accounts/{userId}",123)
.
.
.
.andDo(document("{methodName}",
                    preprocessRequest(prettyPrint()),
                    preprocessResponse(prettyPrint()),
                    pathParameters(
                            parameterWithName("userId").description("userId of the requested user.")
```

In my index.html, the path params are documented like I expect. What I found was that the table header of my path parameter docs is just the way I want it:

[image]

So had a look at the [default snippets](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-restdocs/tree/master/spring-restdocs-core/src/main/resources/org/springframework/restdocs/templates/asciidoctor). [Here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-restdocs/blob/master/spring-restdocs-core/src/main/resources/org/springframework/restdocs/templates/asciidoctor/default-path-parameters.snippet) I found the following:

[image: Docs]

So it seems that there is/was a problem with the curly brackets. I tried to copy that `+{{path}}+` in a custom http-request.snippet. No success. I also tried to remove the `nowrap` option but again, the in the path the value shown insted of the variable name.
Can someone tell me what might be the problem here? I hope I geave enough details.

Comment: To avoid anyone wasting time trying to answer this question, it was also cross-posted to GitHub issues: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-restdocs/issues/706

Comment: thanks for the hint @AndyWilkinson . I've implemented a solution so far but how can I make spring boot use my CustomHttpRequestSnippet class instead of the one provided by rest docs?

Comment: I've updated my comment on the GitHub issue. You can configure the default snippets as described in the references documentation: https://docs.spring.io/spring-restdocs/docs/current/reference/html5/#configuration-default-snippets

Comment: Thanks. I've created a new Question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65680019/spring-rest-docs-error-when-creating-custom-templatesnippet
It'll be kind if you may have a look at it. It's basically about the implementation and the including process

Comment: @AndyWilkinson I tried the solution but now all my Mockito Mocks are null. I updated my question

Comment: Repeatedly editing your question so that it's a moving target isn't a good way of getting help. Please ask separate questions that are as small and as focussed as possible, including a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) each time.

Comment: Ok, sorry I thought it is the same context and still not solved. I create another